# slicing of multi-dimensional list without numpy

Tags: python, slice

trying slicing of 2D list having dimensions = (3 X 3), whch results in 4 sub lists of (2 X 2) [ without numpy and other possible libraries ]

```
lis = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
print(lis)

dex = list([])

for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,2):
        dex.append( [ lis[i:i+2,j:j+2] ] )
#       print( lis[i:i+2,j:j+2] )
```

expected :

```
 [ [[1,1][2,2]], [[1,1][2,2]], [[2,2][3,3]], [[2,2][3,3]] ]
```

getting : TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: Can you explain again what should be the result? It would be clearer if all the elements were unique. Do you want the top-right, top-left, bottom-left and bottom-right 2x2 sub-matrix?

Comment: @tobias_k yes sir, totally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use list comprehension to get the same effect. For a 3D list, you'd have another comprehension inside that.

Instead of `[lis[i:i+2,j:j+2]]`

Use `[x[j:j+2] for x in lis[i:i+2]]`

The output of that is `[[[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [3, 3]], [[2, 2], [3, 3]]]`